# Escape a '%' in a mySQL query being executed via python with LIKE and % wildcards

Tags: python, mysql, escaping, wildcard

I'm trying to match a string with a '%' in it through a LIKE operator but this gives me a python `TypeError` due to the formatting getting messed up.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE "%exam\%ple%"
```

In python the query would look like this due to escaping the LIKE wildcards

```
match = "%%exam\\%ple%%"

query = """
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE "%s"
""" % (match)
```

Yet this still throws me the same error.

How would I write the query in python to search `table` where `name` matches all instances of `"exam%ple"`?

Comment: Can you share your python code?

Comment: @Mureinik updated see edit above

Comment: According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) you can specify an alternate escape for the wildcards. So you could do `name LIKE '%exam|%ple%' ESCAPE '|'`

Comment: cant you use conn.escape_string()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape the % instances in the string that is to the right of the % in the generation of the query so:

```
match = r"%exam\%ple%"  # Use r string to avoid having to double \s
query = """
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE "%s"
""" % (match)
print(query)  # as a check
```

Results in:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE "%exam\%ple%"
```

Also note that you can effectively escape, i.e. make literal, % characters by doubling them, i.e. %d = insert number but %%d = insert "%d" however you will need to double for each % operation that you are performing.

A better alternative would be to use the string `format` command which is available in both python 3.4+ any python 2.7. This uses {} as a marker for insertion points, (it is classed as a mini-language), and will not touch your % signs.

```
In [2]: "{} == {}".format(1,2)
Out[2]: '1 == 2'

In [3]: match = r"%exam\%ple%"  # Use r string to avoid having to double \s

In [4]: query = """
   ...: SELECT *
   ...: FROM table
   ...: WHERE name LIKE "{}"
   ...: """.format(match)

In [5]: print(query)

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE "%exam\%ple%"
```

Comment: In mySQL this is valid, but python throws an error `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string'`, it treats the escape `%` as a format string variable.

Comment: You can effectively escape, i.e. make literal, % characters by doubling  them, i.e. %d = insert number but %%d = insert "%d"

Comment: I've tried this, but when I escape a `%` by doing `%%` in a `LIKE` clause, the query ends up searching for something like `tes%%t` as oppose to `tes%t`

Comment: @nyvokub you need to only double the %s that need to be retained in the string to the left of the % operator, i.e. "The amount is %d%%" % (22.5,) or "The amount is %s" % ("22.5%", ) if you see what I mean.